# Is there an R package for working with very large graphs?

Tags: r, graph, large-data

I'm trying to find maxflow/mincut in a very large graph using R Language. I tried using RBGL package, which is a wrapper for some C library, so it's supposed to be much faster than pure-R packages, but I'm getting stuck on creating a graph object.

- Creating graphAM object causes an error, that there's not enough memory to allocate vector of size 100Gb
- Creating graphNEL object takes a very long time(waited over an hour and it still didn't finish).

In my graph I have only 154403 vertices and 618082 edges. Is there a package in R, that can efficiently work with this kind of graph and has necessary function to calculate maxflow/mincut?

I expect that it should create an object and calculate maxflow/mincut in around 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used igraph successfully with some big graphs, though its hard to predict if it will meet your 5 minute mark.

igraph has functions for max_flow (https://igraph.org/r/doc/max_flow.html) and mincut (https://igraph.org/r/doc/min_cut.html).

Comment: It works! Takes around 3 minutes for my graph. Thanks!